# How to handle multiple users purchasing a subscription from a single Apple ID, or group them based on subscription group?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

Currently, we want to implement auto-renewable subscriptions on iOS. We face a problem where users can purchase multiple subscriptions on a single Apple ID linked to the device. We are having 3 subscription plans as **Regular (Monthly), Regular (Yearly), and Special (Yearly)**. Now, we have decided that Regular plans will be configured in a separate subscription group and special plan on the other since we don't want the Regular users to know that there is a special plan that is less costly than theirs. (Through Manage Subscription Settings on the device)

**Scenario 1:** If User A subscribes to the Special plan on his Apple Id, his subscription gets active. Now, if on the same Apple ID, user B logs in to the app and is a Regular user then he can purchase any of the Regular plans. But the issue is User A's receipt and User B's receipt cause problems sometime later since their receipts are created on the same Apple ID. We are not able to restrict User B to purchase from User A's device in this case, since the `original_transaction_id` of the subscription are different as they are from the different subscription groups.

**Scenario 2:** If we do keep both the Special and Regular subscription plans in the same group, we don't want the regular users to get access to the Special plan as it is cheaper and will affect the profit that we get.

Has anyone come across these scenarios, what would be the ideal way to handle these scenarios?

Comment: Store the original transaction ID of all subscriptions in the receipt against the user in your database. When User B activates the subscription either remove all subscriptions from User A (And show a message that you are removing User A's subscriptions since they have now associated their Apple ID with User B OR don't allow activation of the subscription against User B - Inform them that the subscription has been applied to User A

Comment: @Paulw11, how can I achieve that, since the original transaction id will be different for User A and User B if they are opting out for plans present in the different subscription group. So I won't be able to inform either User A or User B of this scenario.

Comment: Since they have the same Apple ID the receipt will have the full in app purchase history

Comment: @SagarMehta Won't the user be able to see all subscription groups on the Manage Subscriptions page on the device?
So, even if they purchase a Regular plan subscription, they can switch to the Special plan on the Manage Subscriptions page on the device? Isn't it?

Comment: @Areeb, you're right, so we separated out the subscription groups. And also not allowing users to purchase 2 subscriptions on the same Apple ID for different subscription groups